# What is class property of an object point to - MyClass.class

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-languages

In java, what is the need/use of ".class" property of an object. e.g., MyClass.class. What does .class point to.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of the class `Class`.

http://javadocs.org/class

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need some **typing information**, e.g. when you do some **reflection**.

The **.class** is specially handled by the compiler and is interpreted as a **Class** instance.

If you've used C# before this is the equivalent of the **typeof** operator.

e.g. if you want to dynamically get the full name of a type you can do:

```
System.out.println(String.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful in some circumstances where you want to say 'any object of a particular class'. For example, in JUnit you use the class object of a class to indicate that a test is expected to throw an exception of a particular class.

They can also be useful in some advanced uses of generics, to ensure that methods are applicable only to objects of a particular type. For example, Spring `HttpMessageConverter` objects use them.

Comment: What is the use of any "interface.class" property in java ?